# Using exports in package.json for local packages

Tags: npm

I have a project with two packages:

```
api/package.json
api/src/hello.js
shared/package.json
shared/src/foo.js
```

`api` depends on `shared` via a relative dependency:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "shared": "file:../shared"
  }
```

`shared` exports its src folder:

```
  "exports": "./src"
```

However, when I try to `import foo from "shared/foo"`, it does not work, unless I `import foo from "shared/src/foo"`. I understand the `exports` block is supposed to resolve that, so either I'm using it wrong or it doesn't work with local packages. What am I doing wrong?

Sample repo: https://github.com/crummy/monorepo-test

Comment: What versions of node and npm are you using?